# Using FontAwesome 4.0 with Bootstrap 2.x - Still possible?

Tags: font-awesome

I see lots of documentation talking about FontAwesome 4.0 and Twitter Bootstrap 3.0 (Less/Sass) - but nothing regarding Bootstrap 2.x or the issues of trying to get them to work...

Anyone had an attempt at this already? The new class names ring alarm bells..

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just upgraded from FontAwesome 2.x to 4.0 using Bootstrap 2.x and it **does** work.

Had to do a substantial find and replace to convert the "icon-something" to "fa fa-something" class names.

The 'font' folder is now 'fonts' although I'm unsure if that was a change in FontAwesome v3.x or 4.0.

A fair few of the icon names have changed but I guess it's just one of those (annoying) things.

I'd love to understand the reasoning for it.

Upgrade guide listing changes: https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/wiki/Upgrading-from-3.1.2-to-4

Answer (score 2):

I have it working with BS 2.3.2 seems fine. But the class has changed from icon-name to fa fa-name. God knows why!!!

Comment: +1, Just to inform you and future readers I think they added the namespace fa to the front and changed it from icon-name to fa fa-name so that it could avoid naming conflicts with most sites and plugins.  My team is building a browser plugin using fa 3.x and I noticed some sites Stack Overflow included have classes like icon-inbox, which is the same as fa 3.x, but their icon isn't a fa icon in fact it doesn't even have a :before pseudo element it's just a background image so fa adds the :before pseudo element so it makes two inboxes. This is the reason I am switching to get the fa namespace.